# How to loop through a list of components in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I may have gone about this completely the wrong way from the beginning so all advise is welcomed.

I am trying to create a basic page with inputs on the right and hints for the inputs on the left and when you focus on the inputs the appropriate hint is highlighted on the left.

There is a JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/210693/

This will not work as I do not know how to find the appropriate hint to highlight (and set isHighlighted to false on all the other hints).

I managed to get a working example by adding a highlighted prop on the field object and not using a hint component. However in reality the fields data will come from the database so it won't have a highlighted parameter so a hint component seemed more sensible.

To put my question in simple terms: How can I find the relevant hint component when focused on an input?

JS Fiddle showing functionality without a component: https://jsfiddle.net/as2vxy79/

Broken JS Fiddle trying to use a component: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/210693/

Here is the JS outside JS Fiddle:

```
Vue.component('hint', {
    template: `
    <div class="hint" :class="{'highlight-hint': isHighlighted }">
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
        isHighlighted: false
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    fields: [
      {
        'id': 'name',
        'hint': 'Put the name here'
      },
      {
        'id': 'description',
        'hint': 'Put the description here'
      },
      {
        'id': 'more',
        'hint': 'Put more here'
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onFocus(focusedField) {
        // Somehow loop through the hints
      // I am aware there is no "hints" property this is an example
      this.hints.forEach(function(field) {
        field.isHighlighted = (focusedField == field.id)
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: "*the fields data will come from the database so it won't have a highlighted parameter*", why does that prevent you from adding it?  You shouldn't be telling the component that it is highlighted, you should be setting it on the data as you are in your working example and letting the component learn, from the data, that it should be highlighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: you don't need a direct reference to the components displaying the hint because you can solve this problem using **reactivity**.

Only thing you need to do is add a data field which stores the field id you want to highlight and then conditionally add a class to the hint you want to highlight based on the selected id (or render the components conditionally).

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    highlightedFieldId: '',
    fields: [
      {
        'id': 'name',
        'hint': 'Put the name here'      },
      {
        'id': 'description',
        'hint': 'Put the description here'      },
      {
        'id': 'more',
        'hint': 'Put more here'      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    onFocus(focusedFieldId) {
      this.highlightedFieldId = focusedFieldId;
    }
  }
})
```

[Here's an update](https://jsfiddle.net/etgw2kjy/) to your Fiddle.

---

**NOTES:**

- If you really need direct references you can use the `ref` [directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) (this also works in a list of components generated by `v-for`).
- You should probably think about using tooltips for the hints. E.g. using Element UI's [Tooltip](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/tooltip#tooltip).

---

**UPDATE:**

So, [here's a solution](https://jsfiddle.net/dzo3h1xr/) using the `ref` directive to obtain a reference to the highlighted `hint` component. You can see that I used the field id in `:ref` but you still get an array from `this.$refs[focusedFieldId]` since there is a surrounding `v-for`. Other than that, it's pretty simple.

I also updated the `hint` component to accept the `is-highlighted` prop so it can change its class on its own (you previously used a data property for this which does not result in a component update).

Comment: Cheers that's awesome. I realised I may also need to scroll the hint into view so being able to access the specific hint via ref would be great. Are you able to explain that? Simply using ref="hints" on the component results in a non-associative array so it's not clear how to access the appropriate hint.

Comment: And in regards the tooltip, each hint may be quite large (2/3 paragraphs) hence a guide in the sidebar that scrolls into view seems more appropriate :)

Comment: @robjbrain Ok, yeah, this probably is too much for a tooltip. ; ) Check my update for an example of how to get the component reference using the `ref` directive.

Comment: Thanks, i've accepted your answer because it definitely resolves the original question although i'm still a little unsure how to work with the component within $ref, standard methods such as .scrollIntoView() don't seem to be available. Although this is probably more a basic naivety of vuejs and I need to do some more reading/practising.

Comment: Thanks! This is simple as well. You just need to access `$el` on the `hint` component obtained from the `$refs` collection: `this.$refs[focusedFieldId][0].$el` gives you the native element which is the root node of the `hint` component. From there you can work with `scrollIntoView` or `Window.scrollTo`: [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/dzo3h1xr/20/). Good luck!